# Get project location from controller

Tags: servlets, file-upload, path

**Question 1**

Here's my project folder,

[image: folder tree]

> How can I call **images** folder from **UploadContoller**?

I already tried with

```
request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/images");
```

But it didn't work.

---

**Question 2**

[image: project tree]

> How can I call **images > a1.jpg** from **view > a..jsp**?

I already tried with

```
<img src="/images/a1.jpg">
```

But it didn't work

**SECOND PART**

The problem is ok only when i strore my project like (C:\myproject). The problem is When is save my project in other location like (D:\NewFolder\myproject).

Way 1

> request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
>
> --> C:\SpringToolSuite\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.2.RELEASE\base-instance\wtpwebapps\myproject\

Way 2

> request.getContextPath() + "/images/";
>
> -->/myproject/images/

Why i cannot file my project real location. 
Right Now, my project is under

> C:\Users\Star\Downloads\myproject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
request.getContextPath()
```

the above line will give you the context path of your project which is also known as the root of your file tree. Navigate from there.

Answer 1

```
request.getContextPath() + "/images";
```

Answer 2

```
<img src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/images/a1.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks, it work. But, it save to C:>myprojectname>images. Actually, my project is under D:>...>myprojectname.    Anyway???

Comment: Thanks again. Roshana ...it's working.